# What is the meaning of “dress as hot dogs”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In the book [English for Everyone English Phrasal Verbs](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/english-for-everyone/9780744044843/), there are following skit as

"Sam wanted his waiters to dress as hot dogs. He backed down when they threatened to quit."

I'm confusing the situation. Does Sam request his waiter to have a hot dog costume? Or is there any special meaning in "dress as hot dog"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  "dress as hot dogs" means to wear a hot dog costume.

So what do you think Sam's job is? Does it make sense now why the waiters "threatened to quit"?

Comment: Aha! Sam is the boss of waiters, and the hot dog costume is for sales promotion?

Comment: You've got it!!